# What is wrong with this code, it doesn't stop when it has to

Tags: java, algorithm

It is a Spiral Order Matrix problem but my code doesn't stop even if the conditions are true.

It keeps on going and when dir is equal to 0 it should satisfy the if condition inside while loop but it seems like it doesn't care about if statement.And now I don't know what I can do with this.

```
    int A = 4;
    int L = 0;
    int T = 0;
    int B = A;
    int R = A;

    int h = 0;
    int dir = 0;// (d = 0 L to R) (d = 1 R to B) (d = 2 B to L ) (d = 3 L to T)

    while (T <=B && L <=R ){
        if (dir == 0){
            for (int i = L; i < R - 1; i++ ){

                h ++;
                ans.get(T).add(i);
            }
            dir ++;
            T ++;
        }
        else if (dir == 1){
            for (int i = T ; i < R; i++){
                h++;
                ans.get(i).add(h);
                R--;
                dir ++;
            }
        }
        else if (dir == 2){
            for (int i = L; i < B; i++){
                h++;
                ans.get(B-1).add(h);
            }
            dir++;
            B--;
        }
        else if (dir == 3){
            for (int i = T; i <= R; i++){

                h++;
                ans.get(i).add(h);
            }
            dir = 0;
            L++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly is it going? did you debug and see?

Comment: L --> left coloum ,T --> top row, R --> right coloum, B --> bottom row and A --> length at which u have to perform the operation

Comment: It is easy to start blaming the tools when you can't see the errors. But I can assure you: the JVM does not ignore any if-statements. Step through your code with a debugger and look at how it behaves. If you don't know how to do that, learn it. It's a fundamental skill.

Comment: sorry for that, yes I have got the answer now, but it is easy to blame others when you are exhausted to know the answer. I am really sorry.

Comment: Not really connected to the question itself but please, use some reasonable variable names. By convension variable names in Java start with a lowecase letter. You could name your variable something like `leftColumn`, `rightColumn`, `topRow`, `bottomRow`. When it comes to `A` I have no idea at all how it relates to length of something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You placed the `dir++` inside the for loop for `dir==1`. If you place it properly, it will work properly!